# Как сделать чтоб новое окно после закрытия старого становилось активным? tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
    entry.place(x=10, y=10)
    entry.focus_set()
    window.mainloop()
```

Этот код создает окно, которое принимает текст.
Если окно  закрыть, оно через секунду открывает новое такое же, но проблема-это новое окно не активно(туда нельзя писать текст до нажатия мышкой).
Как это исправить?

Comment: Не проще вообще запретить закрывать окно?

Comment: Задача в другом

Comment: Тогда опишите задачу в вопросе.

Comment: Как сделать чтоб новое окно после закрытия старого становилось активным? tkinter, python

Comment: Это не задача, это то как вы хотите задачу решить.

Comment: window.mainloop() внутри цикла while? Ну-ну.

Comment: цикл while всегда будет ждать пока окно закроется и заново его создавать. Что тут такого?

Comment: Если ты нажимаешь кнопку закрыть приложение, то приложение должно закрыться наверное.

Comment: Да, но через секунду оно заново запустится

Comment: Нахера оно должно запустится? Я как пользователь закрыл приложение и хочу что-бы оно закрылось, выключить компьютер. А ваше постояно работающее приложение не даст завершить работу ПК.

Comment: зачем это сюда писать если задача ясно написана?

Comment: Вы посмотрите туториалы по созданию окон на Tk.

Comment: Да. Этого там нет

Comment: Если хочешь что-бы окно было в фокусе то сначала на него фокус поставь.

Comment: В общем, под windows смотрите в сторону SetForegroundWindow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161643/4752653 Под другими системами решения будут другими.

Comment: Александр, типо window.focus_set()? Я пробовал, но не работает

Comment: insolor, спасибо! Оно работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter
import time
import ctypes
alt_key = 0x12
extended_key = 0x0001
key_up = 0x0002

#   store some stuff for win api interaction
set_to_foreground = ctypes.windll.user32.SetForegroundWindow
keybd_event = ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event

def steal_focus():
    keybd_event(alt_key, 0, extended_key | 0, 0)
    set_to_foreground(window.winfo_id())
    keybd_event(alt_key, 0, extended_key | key_up, 0)

    entry.focus_set()

while True:
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
    entry.place(x=10, y=10)
    entry.focus_set()
    entry.focus()
    window.after(20, steal_focus)
    window.attributes("-top", True)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]